# NodeJS - Auto Module Loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, modules

I took some time to try and solve a problem. I am building a basic Node + Express API. In the app I have created a models folder and will be adding new models as I continue development.

I attempted to write a small autoloader for a directory to automatically load and export my models. This code snippet should work for any modules not just my models folders.

**See the following code:**

loader.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
// Autoload modules.
module.exports = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
                    // Ignore current file (loader.js)
                    .filter(f => !__filename.includes(f))
                    // Require all files in directory
                    .map(f => require( `./${f}` ))
                    // Add to final module.exports object using class name
                    .reduce((prev, curr) => ({...prev, [curr.name]: curr}), {});
```

**My folder structure for the models:**

[image: Structure of my models directory]

**How I import the models into my Routes file:**

author.route.js

```
const { AppResponse, Author } = require('../models/loader');
```

**The question**:

Is this a good idea to do something like this? My reasoning is that it would minimize changes when I commit and not require any modifications to my code should I decide to add new functionality to my routes and models folders.

What caveats are there to doing this and would there be a better approach?

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: I appreciate critisism but perhaps explain the downvote? I would gladly ammend my question should it not have sufficiant information.

Comment: You need to supply more of your code for it to be reviewable; small excerpts are not reviewable.

Comment: @Reinderien This is clearly a Node.js design pattern in itself and not an “excerpt”

Comment: @Reinderien I've added more detail. Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The major reason for not doing this is that dynamically requiring modules breaks static analysis.

In a pure Node.js project, this does not have major repercussions aside from breaking IDE's autocompletion. Everything else will still work as expected.

**diving deeper**

Should this pattern be used in a webpack project for instance (targetting server or client), it would fail, as bundlers need to [statically compute](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) the dependency tree at compile-time.

The `require()` function  ([CommonJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html)) was implemented in Node because, at the time, the core Javascript language didn't have the concept of modules. However this has changed, as [ES modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) are now available in all evergreen browsers, and in Node 13.x [without a feature flag](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

The new keywords `import` and `export` do not support variable interpolation for the purpose of static analysis, and are even required to be declared on top of the module. In practice, this makes the patterns `if (dev) { require('debug') }` or  `require(name)` unusable, once adapted to ES modules.

**recommendation**

In my opinion, this is a case where anything “clever” you try to make will just make the code harder to read and maintain. I've been down that path too, and I can tell you that the long-term costs are not worth the 2 seconds it will take you to add manual exports to your files. In my experience, reading code is 10 times more costly than writing it.

You also don't even have to create `index.js` loaders; you can require the files directly. Ryan Dahl, creator of Node, [even said at JSConf 2018](https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://tinyclouds.org/jsconf2018.pdf) that he considered the addition of `index.js` a mistake because *“it needlessly complicated the module loading system.”*

Good luck, and be kind to future-you.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I have not considered the impact of bundlers at all! Clearly this approach would then not be "Future proof" when switching to ES modules.